# Parsing HttpResponse from API into objects

Tags: java, json

I'm working on a Recipe app in the very early stages. I've never used API's before but I get the basic understanding of it, I have done A LOT of searching to get this far but basically here's the deal: I'm using a Recipe API from RapidAPI that can return multiple responses. I would like to parse all of the responses into objects of my Recipe class. I have got the code working and functional but I feel like there has to be a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do. I am currently using a function to parse the String into an ArrayList of Recipe objects using a Try Catch block to terminate when it hits the index out of bounds exception.

The way Rapid API sends the information over is in string format but each recipe is enclosed in its own {curly braces} so I was wondering if there wasn't some way to manipulate the data with that in mind(maybe something with an array?) but haven't been able to figure anything out. Anyways I'm going to include my code and I will also include a sample of what is returned from the API.

`responseString` looks like this:

```json
[{"title": "Recipe 1", "ingredients": "blah", "instructions": "blah"}, {"title": "recipe 2", etc}]
```

```
class RecipeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://recipe-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/recipe?query=chocolate%20chip%20cookies"))
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "myApiKey")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "theApiHost")
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        String responseString = response.body();

        List<Recipe> recipeList = parseResponse(new ArrayList<Recipe>(), responseString.replaceAll("\"", ""), 0);

        System.out.println(recipeList.get(0).print());
        System.out.println(recipeList.get(1).print());
        System.out.println(recipeList.get(2).print());
        System.out.println(recipeList.size());

    }

    static List<Recipe> parseResponse(ArrayList<Recipe> recipes, String s, int begin) {

        try {
            int titleBeginIndex = s.indexOf("title:", begin);
            int titleEndIndex = s.indexOf(",", titleBeginIndex);

            int ingredientsBeginIndex = s.indexOf("ingredients:", titleEndIndex);
            int ingredientsEndIndex = s.indexOf(",", ingredientsBeginIndex);

            int servingsBeginIndex = s.indexOf("servings:", ingredientsEndIndex);
            int servingsEndIndex = s.indexOf(",", servingsBeginIndex);

            int instructionsBeginIndex = s.indexOf("instructions:", servingsEndIndex);
            int instructionsEndIndex = s.indexOf("}", instructionsBeginIndex);

            String title = s.substring(titleBeginIndex, titleEndIndex);
            String ingredients = s.substring(ingredientsBeginIndex, ingredientsEndIndex);
            String servings = s.substring(servingsBeginIndex, servingsEndIndex);
            String instructions = s.substring(instructionsBeginIndex, instructionsEndIndex);

            recipes.add(new Recipe(title, ingredients, servings, instructions));

            parseResponse(recipes, s, ingredientsEndIndex);
        } finally {
            return recipes;
        }
    }
}
```

I am just looking for a cleaner way to parse the data in an array or list of Recipe Objects. My Try... Finally block works but I feel like I'm not doing it the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools can help you to pares json string like `Jackson`,`Gson`.

I wrote a sample code with `Jackson`,hope it can help you.

For more ways to use `Jackson`, you need to learn for yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
    String responseString = "[{\"title\": \"Recipe 1\", \"ingredients\": \"blah\", \"instructions\": \"blah\"}, {\"title\": \"recipe 2\"}]";
    List<Recipe> recipeList = parseResponse( responseString);
    for (Recipe recipe : recipeList) {
        System.out.println(recipe);
    }
}

static List<Recipe> parseResponse( String s )  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<Recipe>>() {
        });
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();

}
static class Recipe{
    String title;
    String ingredients;
    String servings;
    String instructions;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public String getServings() {
        return servings;
    }

    public void setServings(String servings) {
        this.servings = servings;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Recipe{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", ingredients='" + ingredients + '\'' +
                ", servings='" + servings + '\'' +
                ", instructions='" + instructions + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you say Jackson is better than Gson? I found another way to make it work using Json.getJsonAsArray then rewrote my parseResponse class to use a for-each loop that parses each JsonElement "e" in the JsonArray using e.toString

Comment: No， I just use Jackson more often. There are many read-made tools for parsing JSON, choose one that you are comfortable with or that your team uses